Adding additional params in GET request endpoint while using salesforce Named Credentials for callout
I'm trying to connect the NetSuite with the Salesforce using OAuth2.0 RestLet method. For this I have setup the Named Credentials with the https://xxxxxxxxx.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=1236&deploy=3 endpoint.
Now, in order to get a entity we must include certain more parameters in the endpoint. Like this: - https://xxxxxxxxx.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=123&deploy=3&recordtype=customer&id=12345.
But how do I add the additional &recordtype=customer&id=12345 to the callout, whene the base endpoint will be provided by the named credentials.
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
req.setEndpoint(fullURL);
req.setEndpoint('callout:SFNSRestLet');
// Option 1: req.setEndpoint('callout:SFNSRestLet' + '?&recordtype=customer&id=12345') --> Not generating full URL correctly, having additional "?"  
// Option 2: req.setEndpoint('callout:SFNSRestLet' + '/&recordtype=customer&id=12345') --> Not generating full URL correctly, having additional "/"
HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);
System.debug(res.getBody());

Could somebody help me get rid of this or tell me if there is a workaround for this?

What happens when you do  req.setEndpoint('callout:SFNSRestLet' + '&recordtype=customer&id=12345');?
